# Is there any way to require a controller in a component that is not from another directive or component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can I, from a directive or component, require a controller that is **not** from another directive or component?

Here is what I have tried:

#### Attempt 1

Throws Injector Error.

```
angular.module('test', [])
.controller('mainController', function(){
  this.someData = [{
    someKey : Math.random()*10
  }];
  this.someFunction = function(data){
    this.someData.push(data);
  }
})
.component('master', {
  require:{
    main:'mainController'
  },
  controller:function(){
    this.$onInit = function(){
      console.log(this);
    }
  }
});
```

#### Attempt 2

Creates a new copy of the controller – not what I need.

```
angular.module('test', [])
.controller('mainController', function(){
  this.someData = [{
    someKey : Math.random()*10
  }];
  this.someFunction = function(data){
    this.someData.push(data);
  }
})
.component('master', {
  controller:function($controller){
    this.$onInit = function(){
      this.main = $controller('mainController');
      console.log(this);
    }
  }
});
```

To see what I mean in the second example, please see [This Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yngs38Upjba7OHU8kaWw?p=preview).

I doubt there is a way, but if I'm honest I've never fully looked into *how* angular does what it does. Odds are you have to create a new component/directive and you can just include its controller from there, but I was hopeful!

Comment: it will be a better design to use a service to share a state or functionalities

Comment: Yes, and I am aware of that. This is not a question of best practices, but of ability.

Comment: ok just a comment...

Comment: Here's an insight... it is a directive. [ng-controller is a directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.6.2/src/ng/directive/ngController.js#L231-L238). So regarding the abilities, the nearest controller can be required with `require: '^ngController'` (it is not necessarily main controller, just some controller). And regarding 'best practices', it can't, this smells bad. The code above needs no main controller at all. If there should be some global someData and someFunction - make them a service (or two).

Comment: It never even occurred to me that `ng-controller` was a directive. Interesting.

Comment: Yes, that's good thing about Angular 1, every ng thing in DOM is a directive (except ng-app, which is just an attribute).

Comment: Well that does solve it -- estus if you'd make your comment an answer I'd accept it. Though I do see why you wouldn't really want to do what it is that I am saying since most applications will have multiple controllers, this will only work if you are 100% sure the immediate parent controller is the one you need.

Comment: ng-controller is mostly a leftover of previous Angular versions and 'best practices' (inherited $scope, etc) that were propagated by Angular team, while 1.5 is heavily component-oriented. It is acceptable IMO to have AppController with basic init logic for convenience. But requiring it just means that it is misused. Besides the fact that there can be more than one ng-controller (AppComponent wouldn't have this problem) - this is a use case for a singleton service, there are no reasons why depending on directive hierarchy and `require` can be favourable in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ng-controller is a directive](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.6.2/src/ng/directive/ngController.js#L231-L238). So regarding the abilities, the nearest controller can be required with

```
require: '^ngController'
```

It is not necessarily main controller, just some controller.

And regarding 'best practices', it can't, this smells bad. The code above needs no main controller at all. If there should be some global `someData` and `someFunction` - make them a service (or two). It can be injected to any component controller then, disregarding their places in DOM hierarchy.